# How can I find similar words in descriptions from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find all rows that contain certain words in a SQL Server table.

Let's say my table is called TableA and it has the following structure:

```
ID   State            Description
1     LA        Good quality products 
2     NY        Race diversity
3     WA        We are too diverse a group 
4     LA        Environmental problem 
5     LA        Good environment
```

I also have another table called TableB that has a list of words that I want to search for:

```
Word

good quality
divers
environment
```

What I want to do is retrieve all rows from TableA that contain any of the words in TableB, along with the specific keyword(s) found in each row, like this:

```
ID State        Description                                         keywords
1   LA       Good quality products                              good quality
2   NY       Race diversity and environmentally friendly        diversity, environmental
3   WA       We are too diverse a group                         diverse
4   LA       Environmental problem                              Environmental
5   LA       Good environment, good quality                     environment, good quality
```

I could use `'%divers%'` if the data wasn't in a table, but since it is, I need to search for the words within the table.

I could also use 'diver%', but this may miss words like 'air diversity' that I want to include.

If I do '% divers %', also, may it capture all the descriptions containing that word instead of each word?

For exact matches, I have used following query:

```
SELECT ID, State, 
        Description, String_Agg(v.Keywords, ', ') AS Keywords
FROM     TableA as A
outer apply (
    select (Trim(value)) t,
        case when exists 
          (select * from tableB as B where lower(B.Word)=lower(Trim(value))) 
        then Trim(value) end Keywords
    from String_Split(Description, ' ')
)v
where Keywords is not null
group by A.ID, A.State, A.Description
```

However, I also want to search for similar keywords, not just exact matches. Is there a way to do this in SQL Server? If not, is there any similar approach that I could try?

Comment: Using `string_split()` as you do means that you only compare against individual words and so will not find phrases in your keywords such as `good quality`.

Comment: What does "I could use '%divers%' if the data wasn't in a table" mean? You can do `like` queries with wildcards even if the data is in a table (although I'm not sure I understand your requirements enough to recommend it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, state, description, string_agg( keyword, ', ') as Keywords
from (
    select distinct id, state, description, 
           case when lower(Trim(value)) like '%'+lower(word)+'%' then trim(value)
                when word like '% %' 
                then substring(description, 
                               charindex(lower(word), lower(description)), 
                               len(word))
           end keyword
    from tablea cross apply string_split(description, ' ')
    join tableb b on description like '%'+word+'%') v
group by id, state, description
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wRjyKuYT)

This solution is similar to yours, except words in tableB containing spaces, which require special treatment.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and sorry for the late reply. It is very similar to what I am looking for. If I search for the 5th row of my ideal output. It has an additional comma such as **" environment,, good quality "**.  How should I get rid of it?

Comment: Because `environment, ` is treated as whole word. You can eliminate these commas with `replace`, either in input or from output like in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GB3d2KSn).

Answer (score 0):

First, I think the other answer of a full text search is preferable if it meets your goals. However...

I think you could use something like the following to get your expected output (you might want to double check the edge cases to make sure I didn't miss anything in the indexes):

```
WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT id, state, description, word, CHARINDEX(lower(word), lower(description)) pi
 FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB
  ON CHARINDEX(lower(word), description) > 0
)
, cte2 AS
(
 SELECT cte.*, CHARINDEX(' ', reverse(substring(description, 1, pi))) ps, CHARINDEX(' ', description, pi+len(word)) ns
 FROM cte
)
SELECT id, state, description, STRING_AGG(substring(description, pi - CASE ps WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE ps-2 END, CASE ns WHEN 0 THEN len(description) ELSE ns - (pi - CASE ps WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE ps-2 END) END), ',')
FROM cte2
GROUP BY id, state, description
```

You can see it working [in this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MRDhu9Px).

The idea is that the first CTE finds all the rows that have matches and the index where the match occurs. The second CTE then finds the previous space (before the match) as `ps` and the new space (after the match) as `ns`). The main query separates the words out. It is not necessary to use the CTEs, but I found it easier to mock up. Whether you use the CTEs or not, you could probably clean this up quite a bit.